# SQL query not working in PHP code

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following code:

```
  <?php
$sqla = "SELECT A.sDomain ,valid, invalid FROM ( SELECT SUM(count) AS valid,\n"
    . "SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ref_url,\'http://\',\'\'),\'https://\',\'\'),\'www.\',\'\'),\'/\',1) AS sDomain \n"
    . "FROM ref_records WHERE user_id = 6969 GROUP BY sDomain ORDER BY 1 DESC) as A\n"
    . "INNER JOIN\n"
    . "( SELECT SUM(invalid) AS invalid,\n"
    . "SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(ref_url,\'http://\',\'\'),\'https://\',\'\'),\'www.\',\'\'),\'/\',1) AS sDomain\n"
    . "FROM ref_records WHERE user_id = 6969 GROUP BY sDomain ORDER BY 1 DESC) as B\n"
    . "on A.sDomain=B.sDomain"; 

$resulta = mysqli_query($con, $sqla);     
while($recorda = mysqli_fetch_array($resulta)) {      
echo '<tr class="btn-group btn-group-justified default">
<td>' . $recorda['sDomain'] . '</td>
<td><span class="text-danger">' . number_format($recorda['valid']) . '</span></td>
<td>' . number_format($recorda['invalid']) . '</td></tr>  ';       
}   
mysqli_close($con);    
?>
```

The SQL query works just fine in phpMyadmin, and returns a table with 3 columns: sDomain, valid & invalid. However it throws the following error when I try to build a html table from that query:

```
[15:29:26] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in test.php on line 203
[15:29:26] PHP Warning:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in test.php on line 205
[15:29:26] PHP Warning:  mysqli_close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in test.php on line 216
```

Guess I'm missing something here...

Comment: Nope, that didn't work. The query formatting is correct as it works in phpMyadmin. Guess it's the way I fetch the query results needs rethinking...

Comment: It didn't output anything. Seems it died right when the query was executed "PHP Warning:  mysqli_error(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in test.php on line 203".

Comment: which connection API are you using? `mysqli_`? or `mysql_` or PDO  or did you connect at all? your connection may have failed also.

Comment: Connection is working fine as I have other queries using the same connection code: $con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` and error checking against your db connection and that you chose the right database/tables.

Comment: @ /ping one of us when you get results. I am moving on. Good luck.